# Caching .mid audio files in a game

Tags: java, caching, audio, inputstream

The question may seem really simple. I am working on a game project, so for now I need to implement a sound engine.

I have several audio files to be played. I do it this way:

```
File file = new File("music.mid");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
```

For now I am trying to cache those files to increase performance via HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, File> cache = new HashMap(); //name - key & file - res
```

I check for a file in the hashmap and take it out if it exists and reuse it.

**However, audio resources still seem to be downloaded each time I need to play a file.**
(May be input streams are generated again or so)

And game starts lagging every time.

---

Could you please show me an appropriate way of caching `.mid` files, so they could be quickly accessed and played in an application?

Comment: It looks like you're just caching the `File` objects, which represent the ability to perform file operations, rather than file data per se. It seems like you want to be caching the `AudioInputStream` or the `Clip`; I'm not too familiar with the audio system, so I can't say if those objects will have the lifetime characteristics and data you need.

Comment: @dlev I guess you are right, I should be caching something else, not `File` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `File` object in Java doesn't actually contain the contents of the file, it is only a handle to the file. In fact, the file isn't read until `Clip#open`

Most operating systems cache commonly read files to RAM, so in most cases you don't need to do it yourself. If you need more power over the caching, cache the [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) objects:

> The Clip interface represents a special kind of data line whose audio
>   data can be loaded prior to playback, instead of being streamed in
>   real time.

For example, you can place the clips on a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, Clip> clips = new HashMap<String, Clip>();
for (String fileName: fileNames) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clips.put(fileName, clip);
}

clips.get("music.mid").start();
```

Comment: I think it should work with audio files (not midi). But this is some sort of a joke, it takes like 5-10s just to read that MIDI file (10kb) and play it.